# bootstrap not working for django send_mail

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

In my views.py I have the following code

```
def cpio(request):
    mainDict9=['hemant','jay','yash','Hari']
    args={'mainDict9':mainDict9,}

    msg_html =render_to_string('/home/user/infracom2/JournalContent/templates/JournalContent/test1.html', 
    {'mainDict9':mainDict9,})

   from_email = 'gorantl.chowdary@ak-enterprise.com'
   to_email = ['gorantla.chowdary@ak-enterprise.com']
   subject="TESTING MAIL"   
   send_mail('email title',subject,from_email,to_email,html_message=msg_html,)

return render(request,'JournalContent/test1.html',args)
```

In my test1.html I have my following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="table-secondary"><center>Modified Binaries/components</center></th>
                <th scope="col" class="table-secondary"><center>CRs</center></th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for king in mainDict9 %}
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10px;" class="table-active">{{ king }}</td>
                <td style="width: 10px;" class="table-active"></td>         
           </tr>
           {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
  </table>
</html>
```

The problem is in my GUI the bootstrap code is working fine but when I send the content in mail bootstrap functions are not applying

Answer (score 5):

You should to put css code inside your template. Because most email client will block extra link to avoid execution of malicious code.

For example:

```
 <style>
  body {background-color: powderblue;}
  h1 {color: red;}
  p {color: blue;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not use bootstrap class for `send_mail` function because you need bootstrap `CSS` and `js` for the bootstrap `classes` it will work fine only and only when that `CSS` and `js` are attached with the template. But when you pass it into send_mail there were no `CSS` and `js` in the mail so it will not load the bootstrap classes over there.

You can only use a simple Html tag.

And other things might be if you used `cdn` of bootstrap `CSS` and `js` in `send_mail` `template` then might be it will be applied.